# Azure App Service applicationHost.xdt appears to have no effect

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to get a reverse proxy set up by using Azure Websites, roughly following [this guide](https://tomssl.com/2015/06/15/create-your-own-free-reverse-proxy-with-azure-web-apps/) that explains how to modify `ApplicationHost.config` on such a website - but it doesn't work for me.

I've have this applicationHost.xdt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">  
    <system.webServer>
        <proxy xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <allowedServerVariables>
                <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
                <add name="HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
                <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
                <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
            </allowedServerVariables>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I put it in the `site` directory of my web app.

The transforms appear to get executed (from the transform log):

```
2017-09-06T12:12:20 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 8, 50)
2017-09-06T12:12:20 on /configuration/system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables/add
2017-09-06T12:12:20 Applying to 'allowedServerVariables' element (no source line info)
2017-09-06T12:12:20 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
```

I have indeed four of those blocks.

I still get 500s on setting the headers with rewrite. The detailed error message contains this:

```
<h3>HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.</h3> 
<h4>The server variable &quot;HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL&quot; is not allowed to be set. Add the server variable name to the allowed server variable list.</h4>
```

Not sure what to do at this point. Any ideas?

Comment: Please start with https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Site-Extensions#understanding-what-could-go-wrong-with-xdt-transforms, and figure out if your issue is in the second or third bucket.

Comment: I've got it working with that resource - thanks. I didn't know how to see the resulting `applicationhost.config`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to investigating these issues is to determine whether the problem is with the transform not doing the right thing, or with the applicationhost.config not working as you expect.

You can check the generated applicationhost.config in `D:\local\Config` from Kudu console.

See [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Site-Extensions#understanding-what-could-go-wrong-with-xdt-transforms) for more details about this.

Comment: I have checked a couple of times now and publishing applicationHost.xdt works on my primary slot but no transform happens on my dev slot. The xdt is the same, I have it in the same locations, but no Transform log folder is created even after restarting the app. The 500 I get is an access denied trying to access a header in the URL Rewrite rules of my web.config. I am wondering if this is a chicken and egg thing, with the Transform not happening because it happens later in the pipeline than the URL Rewrite evaluation?

Comment: @Sentinel would suggest a new question as your case looks more specific. Feel free to link to it from here.

Comment: Hello [David Ebbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111888/david-ebbo) - Would you by chance have any solution to this [Rewrite Rule to IIS for HTTPS redirect to HTTP causes null HttpContext.Request.ContentType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871977/rewrite-rule-to-iis-for-https-redirect-to-http-causes-null-httpcontext-request-c)?

Comment: I just added an answer there.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your app service after changing the `applicationHost.xdt`.

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue with the TomSSL [article](https://tomssl.com/2015/06/15/create-your-own-free-reverse-proxy-with-azure-web-apps/), @David Ebbo's [comment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Site-Extensions#understanding-what-could-go-wrong-with-xdt-transforms) ultimately got me to the answer, but felt it was worth adding this to save people some time. It's because applicationHost.config is missing `xdt:Locator="Match(name)"`:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.webServer>
        <proxy xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false"/>
        <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
            <allowedServerVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
                <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
                <add name="HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
                <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
                <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
            </allowedServerVariables>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: To anyone looking at this, make sure to use "xdt:Locator" with a capital L.  The lowercase version as written in the answer won't have an effect.

Comment: Sorry about that, I used a comment from the original article to grab what I though was the corrected applicationHost.config rather than the config I actually used. I've corrected the case in the above.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for fixing. I was just trying to save someone else the head-scratching hour trying to figure out the problem.   I finally applied the patch against the base applicationhost.config using this tool to troubleshoot:  https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/