# Rewrite Rule to IIS for HTTPS redirect to HTTP causes null HttpContext.Request.ContentType

Tags: azure, iis, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am using [HTTPS redirect site extension for Azure](https://github.com/gregjhogan/redirect-http-to-https-site-extension) which has an applicationhost.xdt like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <location path="%XDT_SITENAME%" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
        <system.webServer xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
            <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
                <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
                    <rule name="redirect HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                            <add input="{WARMUP_REQUEST}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I am getting `null` for `HttpContext.Request.ContentType` when Postman sends to HTTP instead of HTTPS and the above takes effect.

I test with this middleware like so:

```
public class TestMiddleware
{
    readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public TestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        if (next == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));
        }

        var requestContentType = httpContext.Request.ContentType;
        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"requestContentType: {requestContentType}");
    }
}
```

I'd prefer to continue handling HTTP redirect in IIS as opposed to the common middleware solution for `.Net Core`.

Does anyone know a parameter to add to `applicationhost.xdt` to address?

**Update 1**: For clarity:

This issue reproduces *only* when I call HTTP and a redirect to HTTPS occurs.

Conversely, when I call using `HTTPS` I get the expected `Request.ContentType` result.

Using the solution provided in this [Answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871977/rewrite-rule-to-iis-for-https-redirect-to-http-causes-null-httpcontext-request-c/48872344#answer-48872344), I get the same behavior.  I am no longer sure the solution will be an edit to 
`applicationhost.xdt`.  Perhaps I need to get the `Request.ContentType` another way?

Comment: Are you sending a `Content-Type` header? :)

Comment: Yep, I can literally append an `s` in postman after `http`.  Same exact request otherwise..  And re-hit send.  Different result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there is now a much simpler way of redirecting http traffic to https: under *Custom domains*, just set *HTTPS Only* to On. Then you don't need any site extension or xdt file.

See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/11/30/how-to-make-an-azure-app-service-https-only/) for more info.

Comment: Thats the perfect solution.  Thanks!

Comment: However, I am getting the same behavior.  I deleted the extension..  Set *HTTPS Only* to On in Azure Portal.  Restarted the web app.  Verified its working, I am indeed redirected to HTTPS.. But middleware test above still returns an `empty string` for `httpContext.Request.ContentType`.  Even republished just to be sure.

Comment: So is the issue related to the fact that there is a redirect, or the fact that it's using https? These are very different things. e.g. what happens if you make no attempt to redirect http to https, but go to https explicitly. Do you see the same issue? If so, you should rephrase your question to remove anything related to the redirect as it is a red herring.

Comment: When I make no attempt to use redirect and call https directly, I get appropriate `httpContext.Request.ContentType`. Will edit for clarity as well as new information that solution may not reside in `applicationhost.xdt`.

Comment: I think the answer may simply be that browsers don't know how to redirect POST requests. So if the second request in fact comes as a GET, them it's expected that there would not be a ContentType. If you analyze the http traffic and redirects, you should be able to validate this theory.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to have wasted your time.. I was sending a `Get` in Postman, with `Content-Type` Header to test new logging middleware. I only want to log the body if `Content-Type` is `application/json` but was using a `Get` to test.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Ah, no worries, glad you figured it out!